# How to make textarea elastic with change the div area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem when use textarea elastic using jquery, the problem is i cannot change the div height when the textarea height changed.

I already try using this jquery plugin : http://bensampaio.github.io/jquery.autogrow/

this my index.html :

```
            <div class="col-8" style="padding: 0;">
                <div class="right-chat-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2 chat-item-img" style="padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 0;">
                            <img class="chat-img" src="./assets/services-2.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1" style="padding: 0;">
                                <div class="notification-status online">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-7 chat-item-text" style="padding: 10px 0;">
                            <div class="profile-name ">
                                <span>John</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex profile-status">
                                <span class="profile-online">Online</span>
                                <span class="profile-off" style="display: none;">Not Available</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hide" class="col-2 mt-3">
                            <button class="circle-button color-minimize"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-area scrollbar-macosx" style="position: relative;">
                    <div>
                        <div class="container mt-2">
                            <!-- Receiver chat -->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-3">
                                <div class="chat-content-image">
                                    <div class="upload-image">
                                        <div class="time-image">
                                            <span class="time-item">14:10</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Sender chat -->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mt-3">
                                <div class="chat-context">
                                    <div class="chat-text">
                                        <p>test/p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chat-time">
                                        <p>14:15</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Receiver Chat -->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-3 mb-4">
                                <div class="chat-context">
                                    <div class="chat-text">
                                        <p>ok</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chat-time">
                                        <p>15:00</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-keyboard d-flex">
                            <div class="col-2" style="padding-right: 5px; margin-top: 40px;">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="chooseFile();" class="circle-button color-plus">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8 mt-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                <textarea placeholder="type here..." rows="3" class="keyboards mt-2">

                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                            <button class="send-button"><img src="./assets/Send.png" width="70%"></button>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is my ui output :
[image]

the output is only make textarea changed into down, but the div height not changed. My expected is like textboard area whatsapp web when you push shift+enter textboard area will what i want.

Thank you

Comment: check out https://codepen.io/tibomahe/pen/EKVmPq may be this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use plain css with the ':focus' attribute and 'max-height', or add a class when the user has clicked inside the input field.

```
textarea {
    max-height: 80px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease; // if you want it animated
}

textarea:focus {
    max-height: unset;
}
```

Comment: sorry not like that what i mean, i mean when the textarea height changed, my div class "chat-keyboard" height changed too. you can try in whatsapp web go to keyboard whatsapp and press shift+enter

Comment: thats probably because of the class d-flex. have you tried using align-items, align-self and the other flex-attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the output you want.
You can resize the textarea with the help of following code:

**html:**

```
<body>
<div>
  <p>user resize both the height and the width of the div element.</p>
  <p>To resize: Click and drag the bottom right corner of the div element.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

hope you can understand this.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't know to implement your answer to my project. I already make textarea elastic. but the problem is i cannot make the div between div chat area and chat keyboard was changed when the jquery elastic area run

Comment: if u think my answer is useful please upvote my answer

Comment: if u think my answer is useful please upvote my answer